# Максимальный размер QImage

Tags: qt, qimage

Ограничение на максимальный размер QImage накладывается следующим образом:

```
    QImageData *d = 0;

if (format == QImage::Format_Invalid)
    return d;

const int depth = qt_depthForFormat(format);
const int calc_bytes_per_line = ((width * depth + 31)/32) * 4;
const int min_bytes_per_line = (width * depth + 7)/8;

if (bpl <= 0)
    bpl = calc_bytes_per_line;

if (width <= 0 || height <= 0 || !data
    || INT_MAX/sizeof(uchar *) < uint(height)
    || INT_MAX/uint(depth) < uint(width)
    || bpl <= 0
    || height <= 0
    || bpl < min_bytes_per_line
    || INT_MAX/uint(bpl) < uint(height))
    return d;
```

Однако, при создании пустого изображения формата `Format_Mono`(1 бит на пиксель) размером свыше `32767x32767`, а затем попытке нанесения на него чего угодно, например, drawText, вся часть текста, нанесенная за пределы `32767x32767` обрезается. То есть, просто белый фон размером 40000х40000 у меня создавался, а при попытке нанесения на него- все обрезается. Почему?

Ведь как я понял отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080052/qimage-qpixmap-size-limitations, ограничение именно в физическом размере `32767x32767` имеется только у `QPixmap`, а у QImage дело только в памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Размером 32767x32767 ограничен как QPixmap, так и QImage. 
Это подтверждает и ответ на вопрос по вашей ссылке:

> Both are limited to 32767x32767 pixels. That is, you can think of them
>   as using a signed 16-bit value for both the X and Y resolution.

Comment: нет, читайте ниже, там написано  
"This may be correct for QPixmap, but for the limitations of QImage see @povman's answer." И в ответе povman-а дается исчерпывающий ответ по поводу ограничений QImage